# Challenging formula to calculate amount of hours based on several criteria

Tags: excel, formula, criteria

I am working on a business travel template where I am trying to incorporate some of our policies as follows (additional hours criteria below):

[image: Additional hours scenario]

In cell N15, I need the total number of hours to be added based on the criteria listed on the image below the scenario. I just need to find a formula to work out the number of additional hours. (Means of transport selection is a drop down, all available options are listed in this example.)

Comment: on straightforward trips, it is fairly easy but it gets harder when 2 or more trips are combined and the means of transports are not the same. For the purpose of this example, the person travelling comes back to London after each trip. But in real life, they will carry on their journey which means that hours have to be accummulated depending on the means of transport used which could be half way per type.

Comment: Please take a new screenshot which doesn't include the text discussion - which is just a duplication of what's in your post, anyway. Also, please show the formula you have now, and be clearer about what you even mean by 'total number of hours to be added'. To be added to what? Explain your policy and the purpose of the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: Screenshot updated. I don't currently have a formula, the number of hours are added manually.

Comment: "total number of hours to be added" is the cumulative hours generated by the means of transport used for each journey. The policy is to add hours of work as allowances when a staff member is required to travel, depending on the criteria listed. This number will be added as additonal hours to the number of hours the person will be away for. All I need is the additional hours element of the calculation, the rest if fine. Does that make more sense? if not, I am happy to elaborate. thank you

Comment: I recommend you add in the number of hours per line-item in the spreadsheet and total them up. If I were an employee filling out a time sheet I wouldn't want a complex formula showing me how many hours I got paid for it, I'd want to understand the impact of each component of travel anyway. That'll also make it easier for you to formulize.

Comment: Employees are happy with the policies used, there are very well known. So a formula won't bother them, in fact the formula is to help the person in charge of booking travel as she has to deal with a lot of them therefore saving her time and limiting possible human error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result you want might be achieved with:

```
=3*COUNTIF(K:K,"L*Outbound")+2*(COUNTIF(K:K,"S*Outbound")+COUNTIF(K:K,"L*Inbound"))+COUNTIF(K:K,"S*Inbound")+0.5*COUNTIF(K:K,"T*")
```

For your example returns `9`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was after. It is very much appreciated.